# How to mount volume for stateless service that uses Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

I have a service, that runs on run on kubernetes, uses Apache Ignite to store some data for processing, runs in replication mode with native persistence enabled. How to rightly mount the volume so the data is persisted the disk? Please note, this question is not related to mounting volumes in Kubernetes, rather the configuration/method to enable persistence in service running with embedded Ignite server in Kubernetes.

Note: The application may run multiple replicas.

Edit: As volumes (pvc) cannot be shared by multiple pods, only pod runs successfully, and other pods are in `pending` state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stateless` means the system does not have dependency during its start or execution, but only be as stateless as possible. So, as the need itself is persistence, the Ignite has to be deployed as stateful using the `StatefulSet`. The `StatefulSet` will automatically provision separate volumes & mount it to every pod.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout out Ignite guides for mounting K8 on [AWS](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/kubernetes/amazon-eks-deployment), [GKE](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/kubernetes/gke-deployment), and [Azure](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/kubernetes/azure-deployment)